# Adding short usage notes per folder

Tags: document-library

I was tasked with restructuring our department's Sharepoint library, because people were complaining that nobody finds anything any longer. After consulting the literature, I believe that it is not enough to simply have a different folder structure, and I am trying to apply some more UX-friendly "nudges".

One thing that I would very much like to see is to have a very short text hinting towards how a folder should (or shouldn't) be used, a bit similar to the tag blurb on Stack Overflow sites. But what I am missing is a way to really implement it.

Ideally, this would be visible before the folder is opened. I had hoped that I can just add a site column with "usage notes" and fill it with these notes, but I never found a way to fill this column for folders, only for files. The picture below is a mockup of what I wanted.

[image: Mockup 1]

Another thing I considered is to have some text showing after the folder is opened, above the list of folders and files. I tried adding a separate web part, but its content stays the same no matter where one has navigated to within the library. And I need the text to change for different folders.

[image: Mockup 2]

What are my options to achieve my goal, be it in these places or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure on this point (maybe someone else can expand on why), but the *folder* content type doesn't seem to be customization. If you want a new folder with a new field, you'll have to add the *folder type* content type to the library. To do this you need to go to your

> **Library Settings** > **Advanced Settings** > **Allow management of Content Types** > **Yes** > **Ok**

In your Library settings should be a new table with **Content Types** as the header, and likely **document** as one of the items. Click **Add from existing site content types** and you should be able to find the **Folder Type** content type somewhere in the scrollable box (See image). Click OK, go into that content type and add your column by clicking the **Add from existing site or list columns** under the Columns table for that content type.

Once the column is added, you can create a new **Folder Type** by selecting

> **File** > **New Item dropdown menu** > **Folder Type**

It's properties can be added when you create the item, or if you click the ellipsis ( ... ) beside the items title, then you can select **properties** to edit the columns if you want to add/make changes retroactively.

If you want some more images, I can modify my response with some more. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked as I wanted it to. I haven't had somebody who connects to Sharepoint as a drive test it, but from what I read about content types, it should be just a normal folder plus some extra metadata, so I hope it will work for them too. Also there was no "folder type" in the existing site contents, I had to create it first.